# SSIS Pivot data

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis

is it possible to pivot in SSIS, is there a tutorial for this?

Data is coming from excel.

I have a columns called ID, WeightScores and SugarScores

Data looks like (sorry I don't know how to show this in the question properly..in edit mode looks fine)

```
ID WeightScore  SugarScore
1       34         6
2       18         2
```

I want to repivot columns in ssis called to make ScoreType and Score

it will look hopefully like this  (sorry again I don't know how to show this in the question properly..in edit mode looks fine)

```
ID ScoreType   Score
1  WeightScore   34
2  WeightScore   18
1  Sugar Score   6
2  Sugar Score   2
```

please help / ideas team

Comment: This is an UNpivot.   Did you look at the Unpivot transformation in the toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load to a staging table and then unpivot it. My favorite method is using a cross apply.

```
/* creating data sample
declare @t  table(
ID int ,WeightScore int,  SugarScore int)

insert into @t
values
(1,       34,         6)
,(2,       18  ,       2)
*/

select ID,a.*
from @t
cross apply (values('WeightScore',WeightScore),('Sugar Score',SugarScore)) a(ScoreType,Score)
```

Results:

```
ID  ScoreType   Score
1   WeightScore 34
1   Sugar Score 6
2   WeightScore 18
2   Sugar Score 2
```